# google plus button invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error

Tags: ios, google-plus

I refer to https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in added GPPSignInButton.
but prompt error

: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

and no anticipated red button on the screen.
This problem bothering me for a long time.
thank you.

- (void)viewDidLoad
  {

  [GPPSignInButton class];

  GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
  signIn.clientID = kClientID;
  signIn.scopes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin,
                   nil];
  signIn.delegate = self;

//    [signIn authenticate];
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

GPPSignInButton used xib.

Comment: So are you going to post your code?

Comment: @trojanfoe used xib. Just drag and drop UIbutton and change GPPSignInButton.According to the document operation completely

Comment: Hi @xx11dragon. I hope you must have solved your issue. I am also facing the  same problem. Can you please enlighten the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact you just forgot to add the Resources files to your project.
Go to the directory where you have your Google plus SDK, and drag the whole **Resources** directory to your project.

Now, it should be working.

[image]